# CSS side-by-side DIVs - Dynatree doesn't fill horizontally

Tags: jquery, css, dynatree

I have two side-by-side DIVs in a JSP.  It works well, with one exception: I can't get the jQuery Dynatree to fill the lefthand DIV's horizontal space properly:

[image]

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="sub-title">
   <div id="sub-left">
    <fieldset class="search-fields">
        <legend>Files Found</legend>
        <!-- Add a <div> element where the tree should appear: -->
        <div id="tree"> 
        </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="sub-right">
     <fieldset class="search-fields">
        <legend id="selectedFileLegend">Selected File Contents</legend>
        <textarea name="fileContents" id="fileContents" rows="20" readonly="readonly" wrap='off'>
(select via tree on left)
        </textarea>
     </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#sub-left {
/*    background: #99FF99;  pale green */
/*    border:1px dashed; */
   float: left;
   width: 24%;
}
#sub-right {
/*    background: #FFCC99;  pale orange */
/*    border:1px dashed; */
   float: right;
   width: 73%;
}
#sub-title { 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
.clear-both {
   clear: both;
}

#tree {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
}
```

I of course also use the dynatree CSS. Any idea what's wrong?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#tree` width is set to 250px;

```
#tree {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
}
```

If you set it to `100%` (or remove the width property altogether), it will fill its container (`#sub-left`).

This is also the reason why it extends out of the `#sub-left` container when you have shrunk the window (second image), as 250px becomes larger than 24% of the available size.

Comment: Argh - I looked at this so many times... OK - that got the Dynatree to fill the lefthand DIV, but: now the lefthand DIV overlaps the right (as in 2nd pic) all the time, unless I make the browser really wide.  Could it be related to the overflow or clear?

Comment: I'd suggest making a jsFiddle so myself and others can more easily debug -- it doesn't look like anything in that snippet would be causing that to happen.

Comment: Note - it only happen when the entries in the tree are wider than the space available with the current browser width.

Comment: You can set a min-width on your `sub-title` container to avoid this -- again, if the size of the container is 100px, your tree is only going to be 24px wide (24%). The items in the tree are wider than the current allotted space.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  I put "min-width: 25%;" on sub-title, but the tree's containing DIV still overlaps the righthand DIV when the browser width is narrow.  I've looked over the CSS and don't see any fixed width anywhere, other than margins. Very frustrating!  Any more ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: I should've been more clear: use a fixed width for your `min-width` on `#sub-tree`, e.g. `min-width: 500px;`

Comment: I played with min-width's and got it to work pretty well (except for very narrow browser window).  Thanks for the help.